# Normalize Array methods and return values

Tags: javascript, arrays, libraries, shim

Is there any JavaScript Array library that normalizes the Array return values and mutations? I think the JavaScript Array API is very inconsistent.

Some methods mutate the array:

```
var A = [0,1,2];
A.splice(0,1); // reduces A and returns a new array containing the deleted elements
```

Some don’t:

```
A.slice(0,1); // leaves A untouched and returns a new array
```

Some return a reference to the mutated array:

```
A = A.reverse().reverse(); // reverses and then reverses back
```

Some just return undefined:

```
B = A.forEach(function(){});
```

What I would like is to always mutate the array and always return the same array, so I can have some kind of consistency and also be able to chain. For example:

```
A.slice(0,1).reverse().forEach(function(){}).concat(['a','b']);
```

I tried some simple snippets like:

```
var superArray = function() {
    this.length = 0;
}

superArray.prototype = {
    constructor: superArray,

    // custom mass-push method
    add: function(arr) {
        return this.push.apply(this, arr);
    }
}

// native mutations
'join pop push reverse shift sort splice unshift map forEach'.split(' ').forEach(function(name) {
    superArray.prototype[name] = (function(name) {
        return function() {
            Array.prototype[name].apply(this, arguments);
            // always return this for chaining
            return this;
        };
    }(name));
});

// try it
var a = new superArray();
a.push(3).push(4).reverse();
```

This works fine for most mutation methods, but there are problems. For example I need to write custom prototypes for each method that does not mutate the original array.

So as always while I was doing this, I was thinking that maybe this has been done before? Are there any lightweight array libraries that do this already? It would be nice if the library also adds shims for new JavaScript 1.6 methods for older browsers.

Comment: The example that you've provided - `A.slice(0,1).reverse().forEach(function(){});` - works as expected. I'm not sure what your point with this example is. You state that you would like to be able to chain, and then you give an example with chaining using the existing methods, that works. Please provide examples that *don't* work with the existing methods, so that I can get a sense of what you would be able to write.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas no it doesn’t, because `slice` doesn’t mutate the array like I want - it returns a new array. I can give more examples if it helps

Comment: What about `.pop()`, and `.shift()`? They remove one element from the array, and return that element. Do you want them to return the array instead?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas yes, that is the point: To keep the mutated Array in the instance.

Comment: How would you then extract a section of the array, if all methods return the original array?

Comment: Also, I presume your proposal doesn't include methods like `toString`, `indexOf`, or `join`, since their purpose is to return a String, or Number value, and making them return the array would render them useless. Same goes for `some`, and `every` which are supposed to return Boolean, and `reduce` which is supposed to return a single value. Making these methods return the original array would defeat their purpose.

Comment: Regarding `map`, and `filter`, they return new arrays because that's more flexible. So, if you want to filter an array into a new array, you write `var arr2 = arr.filter( fn );`, and if you want the filter to apply to the same array (by mutating it), you write `arr = arr.filter( fn );`. So you can have it both ways - that's flexible. With your proposal, `filter` would always mutate the original array, and there would be no way to "filter into a new array".

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I think youre confusing `map` with `forEach`

Comment: I can assure you I'm not. What do you mean?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas sorry, I misread your comment. Anyway, I understand that there are useful cases where you want to return a new array, but I’m not interested in that. I just want to mutate to allow chaining, except for maybe a specific method that actually returns a new array, like `a = arr.filter(fn).toArray()` But hey, if there is a library that works differently (except the obvious underscore etc) I’m all ears.

Comment: Strange. I have always found the reverse and sort methods broken because the mutate the array instead of just returning a reversed/sorted array, exactly because mutating functions makes chaining harder. I am curious to why you believe that this would be an improvement?

Comment: I'm confused about several of the methods.  You explicitly mention `slice` but don't include it in your code sample.  Would you want `slice` to return the original array or the new one?  What about `pop`?  Usually that returns the element, not the array, and that's useful for a number of cases.  Similarly for `shift`.

Comment: One other concern would be that the kind of code you're presenting would miss one major factor preventing it from being a drop-in replacement for Array:  `var a = new superArray(); a.push(3).push(4);  assertEquals(2, a.length); a[2] = 5; assertEquals(2, a.length); // oops!!`  You could only add with `add` or `push` (or `splice` I guess), which is not how many people use arrays.

Comment: Yes, it can not inherit the native sparse array behaviour, unfortunaly. Regarding slice, I believe I mention that and I think it should return the same array but "sliced", instead of a new array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is really inconsistent. Yes, they might be a little confusing as JavaScript arrays do all the things for which other languages have separate structures (list, queue, stack, …), but their definition is quite consistent across languages. You can easily group them in those categories you already described:

- list methods:

  - `push`/`unshift` return the length after adding elements
  - `pop`/`shift` return the requested element
  - you could define additional methods for getting first and last element, but they're seldom needed
- `splice` is the all-purpose-tool for removing/replacing/inserting items in the middle of the list - it returns an array of the removed elements.
- `sort` and `reverse` are the two standard in-place reordering methods.

All the other methods do not modify the original array:

- `slice` to get subarrays by position, `filter` to get them by condition and `concat` to combine with others create and return new arrays
- `forEach` just iterates the array and returns nothing
- `every`/`some` test the items for a condition, `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` search for items (by equality) - both return their results
- `reduce`/`reduceRight` reduce the array items to a single value and return that. Special cases are:

  - `map` reduces to a new array - it is like `forEach` but returning the results
  - `join` and `toString` reduce to a string

These methods are enough for the most of our needs. We can do quite everything with them, and I don't know any libraries that add similar, but internally or result-wise different methods to them. Most data-handling libs (like [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)) only make them cross-browser-safe ([es5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim)) and provide additional utility methods.

> What I would like is to always mutate the array and always return the same array, so I can have some kind of consistency and also be able to chain.

I'd say the JavaScript consistency is to alway return a new array when elements or length are modified. I guess this is because objects are reference values, and changing them would too often cause side effects in other scopes that reference the same array.

Chaining is still possible with that, you can use `slice`, `concat`, `sort`, `reverse`, `filter` and `map` together to create a new array in only one step. If you want to "modify" the array only, you can just reassign it to the array variable:

```
A = A.slice(0,1).reverse().concat(['a','b']);
```

Mutation methods have only one advantage to me: they are faster because they might be more memory-efficient (depends on the implementation and its garbage collection, of course). So lets implement some methods for those. As [Array subclassing](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array) is neither possible nor useful, I will define them on the [native prototype](http://perfectionkills.com/extending-built-in-native-objects-evil-or-not/):

```
var ap = Array.prototype;
// the simple ones:
ap.each = function(){ ap.forEach.apply(this, arguments); return this; };
ap.prepend = function() { ap.unshift.apply(this, arguments); return this; };
ap.append = function() { ap.push.apply(this, arguments; return this; };
ap.reversed = function() { return ap.reverse.call(ap.slice.call(this)); };
ap.sorted = function() { return ap.sort.apply(ap.slice.call(this), arguments); };
// more complex:
ap.shorten = function(start, end) { // in-place slice
    if (Object(this) !== this) throw new TypeError();
    var len = this.length >>> 0;
    start = start >>> 0; // actually should do isFinite, then floor towards 0
    end = typeof end === 'undefined' ? len : end >>> 0; // again
    start = start < 0 ? Math.max(len + start, 0) : Math.min(start, len);
    end = end < 0 ? Math.max(len + end, 0) : Math.min(end, len);
    ap.splice.call(this, end, len);
    ap.splice.call(this, 0, start);
    return this;
};
ap.restrict = function(fun) { // in-place filter
    // while applying fun the array stays unmodified
    var res = ap.filter.apply(this, arguments);
    res.unshift(0, this.length >>> 0);
    ap.splice.apply(this, res);
    return this;
};
ap.transform = function(fun) { // in-place map
    if (Object(this) !== this || typeof fun !== 'function') throw new TypeError();
    var len = this.length >>> 0,
        thisArg = arguments[1];
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++)
        if (i in this)
            this[i] = fun.call(thisArg, this[i], i, this)
    return this;
};
// possibly more
```

Now you could do

```
A.shorten(0, 1).reverse().append('a', 'b');
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO one of the best libraries is underscorejs http://underscorejs.org/

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't use a library just for this (it's a not-so-useful dependency to add to the project).

The 'standard' way to do is to call `slice` when you want to exec mutate operations. There is not problem to do this, since the JS engines are pretty good with temporary variables (since that's one of the key point of the javascript).

**Ex. :**

```
function reverseStringify( array ) {
    return array.slice( )
        .reverse( )
        .join( ' ' ); }

console.log( [ 'hello', 'world' ] );
```