# Why do some methods modify the calling object in place and others return a value to be assigned?

Tags: javascript, oop

For example, in JavaScript if you call Array.sort it sorts the array in place:

```
var myArray = ['c','b','a'];
myArray.sort(); // Now the array is sorted
```

Why was sorting in place chosen instead of this:

```
// myArray is preserved, the sortedArray is a sorted copy of myArray
var sortedArray = myArray.sort();
```

Are there best practices for when you should modify an object in place?

Comment: See the documentation.

Comment: You can try cloning the array `myArray.slice(0).sort()`

Comment: @SLaks I read this page and couldn't find any theory or reasons https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: @Kirk: Look at the first sentence.  `sorts elements of an array in place and returns the array`

Comment: @SLaks read the title to my question - I want to know why they chose that way

Comment: Because that's what the spec says.  (do not assume there is a sane reason)

Comment: OK well I am looking for sane reasons for why a language would be designed one way or another, I was just using JavaScript as an example. My question is about the theory and pros and cons of the different approaches

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Normalize Array methods and return values](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13349715/1048572)

Comment: If you want to know why the people working on the spec decided to use an in-place sort method, ask in http://esdiscuss.org/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all in the hands of the developer. It depends on how you are modeling the behavior of the object.

Whenever you call a function from within an object, it is like as if you are asking the object to do something.

If the sort method sorts the elements within the object itself, then the sort method is meant to modify the state of the object. Its like asking the object to sort itself.

In the other case its returning a sorted array. So its like your asking the object to return the data that it contains after sorting it.

In my personal opinion the second case function should be named returnSortedArray or something in that sense. The function sort applies more to the object sorting itself.

If you are dealing with a huge array of data then sort in place should be the best approach, since it will not create duplicate data in the memory.

If you require to preserve the original order of the data for some reason then returning the sorted array and not sorting the object itself will be better.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, Objects and other complex data types are always modified in-place. There are several reasons for this, but this is prominently an efficiency feature. If you wanted to make a copy of an Array, Object, etc. you would need to explicitly clone the instance. It would be bad-practice to do this needlessly, so only do this when necessary.

Some functions such as `concat` seemingly behave differently, but in the case of `concat`, the function is intended to take existing array instances and create a new instance, rather then modify an existing one. One might say that logically these functions should be a property on the global `Object` or `Array` objects, but only newer JS features are being implemented this way, such as `Object.keys`.

Comment: Wrong; look at methods like `concat()` or `filter()`.

Comment: @SLaks True, I'll add a note on that, though those functions are intended to instantiate a new variable, rather than modify one in-place.

Comment: Then what about `String.prototype.replace()`? Surely it could do that in place too :)

Comment: @Jack: Strings are immutable. It can't do that in place.

Comment: @Jack: String is a primitive, not an Object. Interestingly enough, even explicitly declaring a String as an Object doesn't enable this. `var s = new String("abc");s.replace("b", "z");console.log(s);`

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: Yes; it inherits the same prototype.

Answer (score 1):

sort in place - Let's call it sort1
clone and sort - Let's call it sort2

With sort1,
If you want new instance of sorted array preserving the original one, clone and sort.
If you want to sort in place, just sort.

With sort2,
If you want new instance of sorted array preserving the original one, just sort.
If you want to sort in place, you cannot.

Practice for sort1? I am developing a game. For every frame updates, I have to sort every visible objects in z-order and sort in place is much effecient.