# Are there any downsides of using an in-place concat?

Tags: javascript, arrays, implementation, concatenation, in-place

Sometimes I'm annoyed by the memory requirements for `Array.prototype.concat` since it's not done in-place and returns a new array instead of actually concatenating the array passed in the argument to the instance `concat` is called on, like the name would logically imply.

Assuming that cooperating with other libraries is not an issue, would there be any downside (performance, decreased length limit, etc.) of re-implementing it like so?

```
Array.prototype.concat = function (array) {
    this.push.apply(this, array);

    return this;
};
```

Conversely, would this alternative implementation truly decrease the auxillary memory usage to O(1), or would some internal mechanism keep it at O(n)?

Comment: What language are you coming from where "*the name `concat` does logically imply mutating the argument(s)*"?

Comment: Really, you've ran out of memory because of using `.concat`? I can hardly believe. What is your application?

Comment: At least, you shouldn't name this new implementation `.concat`. Rather use [`.append`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Append) or so.

Comment: @Bergi In regards to your second comment, I am not "running out of memory", but rather concluding that it requires O(n) auxillary memory since it essentially creates a copy of both the previous arrays to construct the new array, and in most use-cases I simply discard the reference to the previous one, which makes the copying simply a waste of time and resources.

Comment: We wouldn't call that "auxiliary memory", as it is *result* memory rather. And I'm pretty sure engines can optimise this quite well. Usually you're not under time or resource pressure anyway.

Comment: In regards to your first question, it doesn't seem intuitive that `concat` is not a mutator to me. Why should it not be when `push` is?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13349715/1048572) helps to get an intuition for that.

Comment: @Bergi alright that's fair but it doesn't change my main question.