# Why some methods in JavaScript make a copy of the object invoked?

Tags: javascript, function, methods, reverse, console.log

In JavaScript, some methods make a copy of the object that invoked it while others do not.

For example:

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
numbers.map(function(x) { return x + 1 });
console.log(numbers); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

It makes a copy of "numbers" that you have to set to another variable.

Whereas:

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
numbers.reverse();
console.log(numbers); // [5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
```

It changes the "numbers" directly. Could anyone please explain why?

Comment: Some methods create a new array, others change the array in place. It's mostly done that way for convenience, generally when you map something, you get a new array etc.

Comment: I don't know why this question is attracting downvotes?

Comment: @kodemaster: that's because some people try to scare newbies away instead of helping them to get around. My guess is that, although it is a good question, the answer an be easily googled. You can start with the documentation as charlietfl mentioned.

Comment: The documentation doesn't typically have rationale. "Convenience" is far from a reasonable, well-thought answer. Sadly I don't think you'll find one easily.

Comment: There simply isn't an answer as to "why". There are benefits to both situations though such as being able to filter the same array numeroous times with different filter criteria, and being able to chain some methods

Comment: By the way, your question is marked as `opinion based`. I am not sure if this is actual a valid argument though because the absence of an answer would be an answer by itself.

Comment: You'll want to have a look at [my explanation of the Array.prototype API design](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13349715/1048572?normalize-array-methods-and-return-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the difference in time of incorporation of methods into the JavaScript.

Method reverse was there from the first version of [ECMAScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript).

The map was added relatively recently in the 5th version.

There is a trend to be more functional nowadays among languages. One of the main principles in functional languages is **immutability of data**. Therefore, these new methods of the array (namely map, filter etc) are functional and do not the change source array.

Answer (score 2):

The array methods in javascript is broadly classified into three 
- Mutator methods 
- Accessor methods
- Iteration methods

**Mutator methods** - Ex : reverse(), push () etc : modify the array . As the name suggest these methods mutates the array on which they are called upon.

**Accessor methods** - Ex : include(), concat() etc : - do not modify the array and return some representation of the array.i.e a new array is returned which is modified array.

**Iteration methods** -Ex : filter(), map()- take as arguments functions to be called back while processing the array. In these methods the length of the array is already sampled/copied and the callback is performed on this arrary.

**Generic methods (non-standard)** - EX: join() These methods are generic in nature and is applicable to objects which “look like” Arrays.

The detailed explanation on this can be found in the below link :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Actually *all* array methods are generic. By standard.